# How to hide all toolbars in ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Tags: pdf, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I am using ng2-pdfjs-viewer to view pdf, but i want to remove toolbar and only want page display area, i can i do that.
[image]

Comment: Did you find any breakthrough here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use own custom viewer via input property `viewerFolder`

1. Copy origin HTML from `node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs/web/viewer.html` to your local folder, in example: `app/static/pdf-viewer`
2. Copy origin CSS from `node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs/web/viewer.css` to folder that we create above
3. The edit your `angular.json`. Add this:

```
{ "glob": "viewer.html", "input": "app/static/pdf-viewer", "output": "/assets/pdfjs/web"},
{ "glob": "viewer.css", "input": "app/static/pdf-viewer", "output": "/assets/pdfjs/web"},
```

Then you can edit your own `viewer.css` where you can hide anything you want:

```css
.toolbar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Or you can edit your local `viewer.html` and customize HTML, but be careful - some elements needs for viewer scripts (viewer.js, pdf.js etc)

Comment: P.S. This is by design, this isn't my own solution, guys)